# Posgres Could not translate hostname

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to start a Postgresql server, but get the following error when I run the command:

```
pg_ctl start
```

Error:

```
LOG:  could not translate host name "146.232.222.*", service "5432" to address: Name or service not known
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "146.232.222.*"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

When I run

```
pg_ctl status
```

It tells me that no server is currently running. What could be the problem here? I am running Postgresql 9.2

Comment: You seem to have configured Posgresql to listen on a network inteface "146.232.222.*" which is not a valid interface address. Check your config, you should be able to find the explanation of the options by a web search rather easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have to provide an interface where to listen, and `146.232.222.*` is not one.

You have to edit your PostgreSQL configuration file (probably something like `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf`) and add this directive:

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

That should make it, because you're saying you're listening to all interfaces. If you just intend listening to localhost (i.e., you're not planning to connect to the database beyond the same machine), setting the `listen_address` to `localhost` would be enough.

Comment: See [the postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html) for a list of different things you can set `listen_addresses` to.

Comment: Thanks! It now says "server starting", but never starts a server when I run pg_ctl start. Is there something else I need to do here? Or should the command pg_ctl start or pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/pgsql/data be sufficient?

Comment: Have you run `netstat -atpn | grep 5432`? If there's something listening on that port, the server is started.

Comment: Hey, I checked and there is nothing on that port. The log told me the following: LOG:  invalid CIDR mask in address "146.232.222.0/225"
CONTEXT:  line 90 of configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf"
FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf. Yet, I see another similar mask in that same file! What's wrong with that one then?

Comment: You should place `/24` instead of `/255`